# Uncaught TypeError: map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx is not a function

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have write the following code for showing coordinates of map but I getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx is not a function

Here is my code :

```
map.on('click',function(e){
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel,function(feature , layer){
    var LonLat = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
        LonLat.transform( map.projection,map.displayProjection);
        Longitude = LonLat.lon;
        Latitude  = LonLat.lat;
        console.log(Longitude);
        })
```

Comment: Which version of OL are you using? Method `.getLonLatFromViewPortPx` is from ages old V2 (2013) and does not exist in newer versions. You would use `.forEachFeatureAtPixel` method now, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my friend, you were right, I was using the new version. But now I have used another method to display the coordinates, but I do not think the coordinates are displayed correctly. The two numbers shown to me are (3889586.1245487547, 6296722.285457358). Where do you think the problem comes from?

Comment: `code` map.on('click',function(e){
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel,function(feature , layer){
            let clickedCoordinate = e.coordinate;
            let clickedFeatureCountryName = feature.get('NAME_0');
            let clickedFeatureCityName = feature.get('NAME_1');
            let clickedFeatureAreaName = feature.get('NAME_2');
            let clickedLatitudeCoordinate = clickedCoordinate[1];
            let clickedLongitudeCoordinate = clickedCoordinate[0];

Comment: Please don't put new questions in the comments. If you have a new question, post it as a separate new question.

Comment: ok here is new question [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388489/coordinate-values-are-not-displayed-correctly-in-openlayers)