# Coordinate values ​are not displayed correctly in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, web-mapping

I'm trying to display coordinates of map `click` event. I do not think the coordinates are displayed correctly. The two numbers shown to me are (3889586.1245487547, 6296722.285457358).

Where do you think the problem comes from?

here is my code:

```
map.on('click',function(e){
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel,function(feature , layer){
            let clickedCoordinate = e.coordinate;
            let clickedFeatureCountryName = feature.get('NAME_0');
            let clickedFeatureCityName = feature.get('NAME_1');
            let clickedFeatureAreaName = feature.get('NAME_2');
            let clickedLatitudeCoordinate = clickedCoordinate[1];
            let clickedLongitudeCoordinate = clickedCoordinate[0];
            overlayLayer.setPosition(clickedCoordinate);
            overlayFeatureCountryName.innerHTML = clickedFeatureCountryName;
            overlayFeatureCityName.innerHTML = clickedFeatureCityName;
            overlayFeatureAreaName.innerHTML = clickedFeatureAreaName;
            overlayLatitudeCoordinate.innerHTML=clickedLatitudeCoordinate;
            overlayLongitudeCoordinate.innerHTML=clickedLongitudeCoordinate;
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really simple. Your map is using EPSG:3857 for projections. It seems you want longitude, latitude. You should do

```js
let xy = ol.proj.toLonLat(clickedCoordinate);
console.log(xy);
```

Above solution is for standalone Openlayers library, otherwise, when using JavaScript bundlers like Webpack or Parcel, you should do

```js
import {toLonLat} from 'ol/proj';

let xy = toLonLat(clickedCoordinate);
console.log(xy);
```

See [`toLonLat` API related docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.toLonLat)

The examples above do not unpack coordinates. You may prefer

```js
import {toLonLat} from 'ol/proj';

let [x, y] = toLonLat(clickedCoordinate);
console.log(x, y);
```